# How to copy paste parts of Themes Setups from one theme to another?

Tags: workflow, theme

Is it possible to copy part of Theme colors schemes from one preset to another (eventually via notepad) to get an *almost perfect* theme ?

I ask because **the quantity of the possible color selectors is huge**.

An organic **Theme builder** would be great possibly **clicking on a part of the interface** to choose automatically the selector so you can make changes on the fly, manually doing this is annoying, and usually gives fancy results due to the speed one try to do things to avoid boredom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as far as I know there is no builtin mechanism to do this, at least not directly through the blender UI or in a graphical manner.

You *can* copy individual colors from one theme to another, by hovering your mouse cursor over a color box and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, but I don't think this is what you expect.

Other than than, Blender themes are simple XML files, you can edit them externally using any regular plain text editor.

You can theoretically copy and paste at will between them. If you use some sort of programmer's text editor with syntax highlighting for XML files and possibly code folding for easier navigation it should make the job somewhat easier.